# Configure the XSL defination for both xml's

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two xml's as shown below along with xsl defination of it , Now please advise as shown in both the xmls that there is a tag  now as it is present in Second.xml but not present in First.xml I want to configure
the xsl defination such as it should work for both the cases rite now it is working for Second.xml only I want that xsl defination should be configured in such a way that it should work for both the cases as sometimes in xml we are not getting the value of tag  sometimes . Please advise

```
***************
    First.xml
****************
<productClassificationIdentifier>
            <ClassificationId>1022</ClassificationId>
            <ClassificationName>AAABBB</ClassificationName>
            <Reference>FFF</Reference>
    </productClassificationIdentifier>


***************
    Second.xml
****************
<productClassificationIdentifier>
            <ClassificationId>1044</ClassificationId>
            <ClassificationName>CCCDDD</ClassificationName>
            <Reference>JJJ</Reference>
                <ClassificationIdScheme>FirstClassification</ClassificationIdScheme>
        </productClassificationIdentifier>


***************
    XSL Defination
****************

        <xsl:param name="abvIdVar"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$abvIdVar">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./ClassificationIdScheme = 'FirstClassification'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./ClassificationId"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Please advise Folks..!!

Hi Folks,

I have achieve the solution of it through

```
 <xsl:otherwise>
xsl:value-of select="./ClassificationId"/>                               </xsl:otherwise>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this when condition for first XML where 'ClassificationIdScheme' element is absent, change your when condition with this one:

```
  <xsl:when test="./ClassificationIdScheme = 'FirstClassification' or not(./ClassificationIdScheme)">
    <xsl:value-of select="./ClassificationId"/>
  </xsl:when>
```